# user select a name(key)in a dictionary and add 6 numbers as its value,

Tags: python, dictionary

searching for the best way to get user input for a key value, the 1 below creates the dictionary from the player list and adds an index as its value but thats not really what i want, any suggestions appreciated

```
import collections
Players = []

names = {}

#add player names
AddPlayers = int(input('How many players do you want to add: \n'))
for i in range(AddPlayers):
    if i < AddPlayers:
        item = input('Enter Player Name:  ')
        Players.append(item)

#create a dictionary from the player list 
d = collections.OrderedDict()

for i,n in enumerate(Players):
    if n not in d:
        d[n] = [i+1]

print (d)
```

Comment: and you want ... what ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, but first please update your title, it looks like a part of your question's body.

Comment: Im looking for a way get user input into  the dictionary to change the key values
User added players this was put in a list 
Then I looped over this to create the dictionary.  Now I want the user to be able to select a name from  the dictionary and add 6 numbers that they choose... Sorry if I wasn't very clear I'm fairly new to programming

Comment: @elfranco91  why not ask for a name, put it as a key, ask for the numbers, and put them as the values. all inside the num of players list instead of creating a list?

Comment: ok thanks ill try that then, and remove the all together then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask for the user name and the numbers. You are already using the for loop, instead of adding the name to a list, create the dic in the loop.

```
names = {}
#add player names
addPlayers = int(raw_input('How many players do you want to add: \n'))
for i in range(addPlayers):
    item = raw_input('Enter Player Name:  ')
    #split by space, commma etc.to have the numbers as a list.            
    numbers = raw_input('Enter Numbers:  ').split()
    names[item] = numbers
```

Comment: perfect, really appreciate that:)

Comment: @elfranco91 can you like my respond if it answer your question?